# How to remove \" from an array of objects

Tags: java, json, string, replace, escaping

I am trying to get an array of objects from the server, using JSON.

The server sends me the following string.

```
"document" : "{\"bc\": {\n    \"b\": {\n        \"t\": 1,\n        \"r\": 1,\n        \"c\": \"none\",\n        \"ipad\": \"Y\",\n        \"n\": \"Table of Contents\",\n        \"o\": 1,\n        \"l\": \"en_US\",\n        \"i\": 1000013253\n    },\n    \"i\": \"CM19014269\"\n}}"
```

This response contains an \" instead of every ". I don't need any \". All I want is a simple JSON response. Any help is much appreciated.

My code : -

```
for (ManageBasketTO manageBasketTO: retList) {

                Long basketId = manageBasketTO.getBasketID();
                BasketTO basketTo = null;
                basketTo = CommonUtil.getBasket(usrCtxtObj, basketId, language, EBookConstants.FOR_VIEWER_INTERFACE,
                        usrCtxtObj.getScenarioID(), EBookConstants.YES, request, deviceType);

                String doc = Utilities.getStringFromDocument(basketTo.getdocument());

                    doc = doc.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", "");
                    doc = doc.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>", "");
                    doc = doc.trim();

                    JSONObject object = XML.toJSONObject(doc);
                    doc = object.toString(4);
                    BasketsInfoTO basketsInfoTO = new BasketsInfoTO(doc);

                    basketsToc.add(basketsInfoTO);



                }



            basketInfoRestTO.setBasketsInfoTOList(basketsToc);

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            responseXML = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(basketInfoRestTO);
            }
```

Also, I tried printing the value of **basketsInfoTO.getDocument**  just after line - `basketsToc.add(basketsInfoTO);` and getting correct response.

However, when I tried to print value of - **basketInfoRestTO.getBasketsInfoTOList**  after line - `basketInfoRestTO.setBasketsInfoTOList(basketsToc);` I'm getting this \" character issue.

Comment: Are you trying to fix this on the client side or the server side?

Comment: You've been given a JSON object - parse it as a JSON object, and then take the `document` field. Don't mess around with string replacements - it's pretty worrying that you're removing the XML declaration manually to start with...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm able to remove \" from response using below line -

```
responseXML.replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Also able to remove \n from response using below line -

```
responseXML.replace("\\n", "");
```

Comment: No, those lines won't do anything useful, because you're ignoring the return value of `replace`. Even if you *did* use the result, this is the wrong solution to the problem, IMO. You've got JSON, so parse it as JSON.